# Hide content from Post Preview

Tags: posts, php, previews

Is it possible to hide content in Post Preview (that is not hidden when the post is published)? I have customised `single.php` quite extensively and there are a few elements that I do not want my authors to load up every time they preview their post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the handy [`is_preview`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_preview) function.

So somewhere in your `single.php`.

```
<?php
if (!is_preview()) {
     // Show stuff that doesn't belong on a preview.
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that function, excellent!